# How to return a link for given text using asp code

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to return a link for the given text.
Here is the code:

```vb
<%
dim t

t = Request.QueryString("txt")
Response.Write("<a href = \" page2.html \" >" & t & "<\a>")
%>
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with the code?, it is not working.

Comment: How is it not working?  What happens instead?

Comment: HTTP 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 1):

To escape the `"` in vbscript, you have to double it. That is use `""` for printing `"`.

```vb
Response.Write("<a href = "" page2.html "" >" & t & "<\a>")
```